# Destroying app on heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I have an app on Heroku but things got messed up when I tried to use two different Heroku accounts with multiple applications. I uninstalled and reinstalled Heroku toolbelt and logged into my account (via the CL) with the app im working on. Things were messing up, so I deleted the app from the Heroku.com apps website, but of course the heroku git repo is still current for the app on the Command Line. If i type `git remote -v`, I get this output

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git (push)
```

What I want to do if completely remove this git repository and start fresh to deploy a fresh instance of it to Heroku. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the current remote reference with

```
git remote rm heroku
```